# Show that the function $f(z)=\frac{z}{z^{2}-1}-\frac{1}{z}$ has a primitive

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Show that the function $$f(z)=\frac{z}{z^{2}-1}-\frac{1}{z}$$ has a primitive, i.e., there exists a function $F'(z)=f(z)$, on the region $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C};\ \lvert z\rvert>3\}$.

I know that, the function $f$ has a primitive $F$ in $\Omega$ implies that, the integral of in any contour closed, is $0$. Any help please!

Comment: Are you also able to show the converse? That if the contour integral of $f$ on any closed curve in the domain is equal to $0$, then $f$ has a primitive? For example, then you could make the Ansatz $F(z) = \ldots$ and then show $[F(z+h)-F(z)]/h \to f(z)$ as $h \to 0$. You would just need to verify that $F(z)$ is well-defined.

Comment: 1/2log($1-z^2$) -log($z$) ?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE While that is true (suitably interpreted), you really need to be careful about the choice of branches to get a function holomorphic on $|z| > 3$.

Comment: @mrf Yeah it was a bad attempt at a joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably also know the converse to result you state in your question, namely:

> If $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$ **and** $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$ for all (simple) closed curves $\gamma$ in $\Omega$, then $f$ has an anti-derivative on $\Omega$.

For your question, let $\Omega = \{ z : |z| > 3 \}$. A simple closed curve in $\Omega$ either has its interior contained in $\Omega$, or it encloses the circle $|z|=3$.

If the interior of $\gamma$ lies inside $\Omega$, then $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem.

If $\gamma$ encloses $|z|=3$, then by partial fractions and Cauchy's integral formula (or the residue theorem if you prefer):
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z)\,z &= \int_\gamma \bigg(\frac{z}{z^2-1}-\frac1z \bigg)\,dz \\
&= \int_\gamma \bigg(\frac12 \frac{1}{z+1} + \frac12 \frac{1}{z-1}-\frac1z \bigg)\,dz \\
&= 2\pi i \big( \frac12 + \frac12 - 1 \big) = 0.
\end{align}

In either case, the integral is $0$, so there is an anti-derivative of $f$ on $\Omega$.